# java file handling restoring the data stored

Tags: java, file-handling

Is there a way that we can see the data in file created through file handling everytime when we re run the program because what is produced in the result of the given code and that is " but if I rerun it with giving different nae inside the command , previous name is not restored . Is this a feature of java or is there any way through which it is restoring the details stored previously.

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class library {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter name");

        // String input
        String name = myObj.nextLine();


        try
    {
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("username.txt");
            fileWriter.write(name);
            fileWriter.close();
        }
        catch(IOException exception ) {
        System.out.println("sorry could not be executed");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code posted in the question will overwrite the existing content of the file. There is a way to append new data at the end of the existing content.

Please use another constructor which takes second parameter, boolean for append/not append:

```
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("username.txt", true);
```